# PlaceHolderMain in Sharepoint showing breadcrumb and title

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007

I am trying to print the breadcrumb and title of a page in share point using a custom.master. I tried using the following code:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server" />
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTitleBreadcrumb" runat="server" />
```

This is not outputting anything to the screen. The breadcrumb and title are displaying in

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server" />
```

However I want to get the content out from there and display it in a different part of the page. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify what's inside your `PlaceHolderMain` and move all of its default contents to somewhere outside. Then, add the `Breadcrumb` placeholders where they belong.

That is, in your master page you make an epmty "PlaceHolderMain":

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
 <!--nothing inside here -->
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

And you will have to fild place somewhere else on your page for the following placeholders:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderSearchArea" runat="server"/>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTitleBreadcrumb" runat="server"/>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea"  runat="server"/>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderLeftNavBar" runat="server"/>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderPageImage" runat="server"/>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderBodyLeftBorder" runat="server"/>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderNavSpacer" runat="server"/>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderTitleLeftBorder" runat="server"/>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderTitleAreaSeparator" runat="server"/>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderMiniConsole" runat="server"/>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderCalendarNavigator" runat ="server" />
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderLeftActions" runat ="server"/>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageDescription" runat ="server"/>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderBodyAreaClass" runat ="server"/>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTitleAreaClass" runat ="server"/>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderBodyRightMargin" runat="server" />
```

See the "minimal master" articles from Microsoft http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa660698.aspx as well as from Heater Solomon: http://www.heathersolomon.com/blog/archive/2007/01/26/6153.aspx

Also, take a look at how Microsoft people have made their master pages bundled with MOSS. You can find them on your MOSS server, "\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\PublishingLayouts\MasterPages"

Comment: How do I override ContentPlaceHolder ?

Comment: Hmm, "override" was not a good term here. Changed my answer a bit, I think it's worth looking at the built-in "publishing layouts".